# How to plot a real-time graph from a pandas series? And reading intermittently from a file

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, real-time, series

I have a file which I loaded in as a panda series. However, the file is to big to load on a single node machine and I'd like to read the file a few lines at a time while updating these values on a graph.

A sample of the file data is shown below:

```
ip,date,time,zone,cik,accession,extention,code,size,idx,norefer,noagent,find,crawler,browser
101.81.76.dii,2016-03-31,00:00:00,0.0,1283497.0,0001209191-16-111028,-index.htm,200.0,14926.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,10.0,0.0,
104.40.128.jig,2016-03-31,00:00:00,0.0,1094392.0,0001407682-16-000270,.txt,200.0,5161.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,10.0,0.0,
```

A sample of my code is shown below:

```
data = pd.read_csv('filepath')
data2 = data[['ip','time','date','size']]
data2['size/MB']= data2['size']/1024
data3 = data2[['ip','time','date','size/MB']]
gr = data3.groupby(['date','time']).sum()
GB = gr['size/GB']= gr['size/MB']/1024

columns = ["size/MB"]
df=GB[0:0]
"""plt.ion()"""
plt.figure()
i=10
while i<len(GB):
    df = df.append(GB[0:i])
    ax = df.plot(secondary_y=['prex'])
    plt.show()
    tm.sleep(0.5)
    i+=10
```

This, however, creates multiple windows. I tried to used `plt.draw()` function in place of `plt.show()` but it doesn't work.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** If you want to plot to the same axes, instead of a new figure, you need to provide an existing matplotlib axes `ax` object to the dataframe's plot method

```
DataFrame.plot(..., ax=ax)
```

**(2)** Calling `plt.show()` opens a window, which takes over the event loop. The remaining script will stop until you close this window. Calling it inside a loop therefore needs to be avoided. `plt.draw()` is appropriate to draw inside a loop in interactive mode. Therefore `plt.ion()` must be called before the loop.

**(3)** Using `time.sleep()` is a bad idea when working with GUI elements like the matplotlib plotting window. It literally lets the application sleep, resulting in an unresponsive window. Use `plt.pause()` instead.

**(4)** You need to specify which data to plot in the plot method of the dataframe. Also you need to clear the axes, otherwise the old plots will stay in the plot.

Now, here is a working script, which animates a dataframe.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":x, "y":y})
df2 = df[0:0]

plt.ion()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
i=0
while i < len(df):
    df2 = df2.append(df[i:i+1])
    ax.clear()
    df2.plot(x="x", y="y", ax=ax)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.2)
    i+=1
plt.show()
```

This is not the most efficient method of animating matplotlib graphs, but it's close to your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and modifications. The code works perfectly, close to the initial code.